# Rails devise mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, pony

Im trying to override devise in order to send mail to activate a user. In the create method  in the registrations controller i have this

```
urlEmail = resource.email.sub('@','-')
Pony.mail(
    :to => resource.email,
    :from => "noreply@mysite.com",
    :subject => "Confirm Account",
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' },
    :body => ("<h1>Welcome To My Awesome Site</h1>
              <p>follow this link to create your account</p>
              <p>http://localhost:3000/confirm-me/stuff?=" + resource.confirmhash.to_s + "/" + urlEmail.to_s  + "</p>") )
```

This url leads to a method to activate the user. Whether this is a good way to confirm an account is beside the point. The problem is that when the Pony.mail(...) runs i get this error

```
uninitialized constant RegistrationsController::Pony
```

i have installed pony and Pony.mail works in the console. I also tried using require 'pony' in the top of the controller file but i get

```
no such file to load -- pony
```

What do i need to do to make this work.

Comment: Do you have pony in the Gemfile?

Comment: Maka sure that you have included `pony` gem for your environment. `Pony` declared as module, so if gem is included, the Pony constant should be there.

Comment: @MarkGuk im actually on rails 3, i installed it using bundle install.

Comment: @MarkGuk do i need to put some sort of statement in config/environment.rb for rails3, if so then what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like problem with bundler. Do you run console in the same RAILS_ENV as your controller test?

Try to copy pony.rb to your lib (from https://github.com/benprew/pony) and require it on the top of controller file. Remove `gem "pony"` from your Gemfile. `bundle install`. Make a test.

If its help, go back to bundler, remove Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install`.

If still have this problem include your Gemfile here.

Comment: "Do you run console in the same RAILS_ENV as your controller test?" Im not good enough in rails yet to even know what that means. (i feel like an idiot.) Anyways i copied pony.rb so now i have lib/pony.rb. Pony is working fine now. Thanks

Comment: @jack run `bundle list` and check if there is Pony gem.